# using file handling with AVL tree

Tags: file-io, avl-tree

I'm given a project in college to use trees(AVL tree, to be specific) and file handling(not very conversant with it).
But I'm not able to relate the two. I only know that files can be used to store data. But in what way can trees and file handling be connected?
I know how to implement trees but how to store it as such in files?

Comment: so the question is how to make a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know any two of the three tree traversals (preorder, inorder, postorder), you can construct the `AVL` tree. Since `AVL` tree is a `BST`, inorder is known. So, store any of postorder or preorder in the file. From that, you can construct the whole tree.

See about [tree-traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).

And also how to [construct tree from inorder and preorder traversals](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-tree-from-given-inorder-and-preorder-traversal/).

Comment: Umm.. it involves storing twice in 2 different orders, right? Actually, I've to create a database using AVL tree. Does that change your answer?

Comment: @wackyTechie No. Inorder traversal is basically non-decreasing order of elements. So, that is automatically known. Store either preorder or postorder. And no, it does not change the answer.